# Reversing the digits of a number in C++

Tags: c++, reverse

I am trying to reverse the digits of a number. I used strings in it. And I am bound to use strings. Program just give last digit and stop executing. For instance if I put 123 as an input and I only get 3. Instead I should be having 321.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b=0;
    cin>>a;
    string str1="", str="";
 for(int i=0;a>0;i++)
 {
 
     b=a%10;
     str=to_string(b);
     a=a/10;
     str1=str1+str;
     
 }
 cout<<str1.length();
 }
```

Comment: You're printing the string _length_.

Comment: Convert the number to a string _once_ and then loop backwards from `str.size()-1` ?

Comment: sorry, I couldnt understand _loop backward_ .

Comment: There is a much simpler way to implement this. Convert the original `int` as-is to `std::string`, then pass the string to `std::reserve()`, then output the string. No manual loop needed. `int main() { int a; cin >> a; string str = to_string(a); reverse(str.begin(), str.end()); cout << str; }`

Comment: @zimmadwaraich Example of looping backwards: `string str = to_string(a); for(int i=str.size()-1; i>=0; --i) { str1 += str[i]; }` - but using the readily available `std::reverse`as Remy suggests is even better.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i got it. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change this `cout<<str1.length();` to `cout<<str1;`.
However it's better to use while loop instead of weird for loop.

```
int main()
{
    int a,b=0;
    cin>>a;
    string str1="", str="";
    cout << a << "\n";
    while (a>0)
    {
        b=a%10;
        str=to_string(b);
        a=a/10;
        str1=str1+str;
    }
 cout<<str1;
}
```

Comment: While this solution works, there's a fair amount of unnecessary overhead when calling `to_string` on a value that you know is between 0 and 9. The simplest way to convert such a value to its text representation is `b + '0'`. The C++ standard requires that the code points that represent the digits `'0'..'9'` must be contiguous and increasing, so this works with any character encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the string length rather than string itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are Printing length of string .length() is a builtin function provided by strings. Try running it again by removing .length() keyword from cout command i.e. cout << str1

Comment: @zimmad Mention not.

Comment: @umair I'm studying in Bahria Islamabad. well, its kinda surprised me, having a pakistanis reply. in which campus you're studying? islamabad?

Comment: Hey since I can see you are a new user, comments are only for clarification or to point out problems in the post please avoid using it other than that, and btw my name is Umar. Actually I am already graduated from FAST-Nu Lahore campus and working as a software engineer.